# inavlid argument(s) /Exception caught by widgets library

Tags: flutter

I have an empty card widget which I used it for opening adding page, my problem is when I pushed from main categories screen I can add main category, but When I used this empty card button on sub category screen of any main category, add screen is opening but when I pushed add I took invalid argument(s) error app is broken. How can ı solve this issue?.

```
class EmptyCard extends StatelessWidget {
  EmptyCard({this.where});
  final String where;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:15.0),
      child: TextButton(
        onPressed: (){
          if(where=="homeScreen"){
            showModalBottomSheet(
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context)=> AddMenuScreen(buttonText: "Menü Ekle",route:where),
            );
          }
          else if(where=="subCategoryScreen"){
            showModalBottomSheet(
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context)=> AddMenuScreen(buttonText: "Tarif Ekle",route:where),
            );
          }
        },
        child: Container(
          height: 180,
          width: 180,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
            color: Colors.black12.withOpacity(0.1),
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline_outlined,size: 100,color: Colors.grey.shade400,),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class AddMenuScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  AddMenuScreen({this.categoryId,this.buttonText, this.route});
  final int categoryId;
  final String route;
  final String buttonText;
  static String id="addMenuScreen";
  @override
  _AddMenuScreenState createState() => _AddMenuScreenState();
}

class _AddMenuScreenState extends State<AddMenuScreen> {
  final stickerList= List<String>.generate(23, (index) => "images/sticker$index");
  int selectedIndex=-1;
  Color _containerForStickersInactiveColor=Colors.white;
  Color _containerForStickersActiveColor=Colors.black12;

  String chosenImagePath;
  String newCategoryName;
  int addScreenImageNum;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Container(
        color: kColorTheme9,
        child: Container(
          height: 400,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(40),topLeft: Radius.circular(40)),
          ),
          child:Padding(
            padding:EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: kColorTheme2,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(90)
                  ),
                  child: TextField(
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontFamily:"Graduate",
                      fontSize: 20,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    onChanged: (value){
                      newCategoryName=value;
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border:OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(90),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.teal,
                        ),
                      ),
                      hintText: "Menü ismi belirleyin",
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
                        fontFamily: "Graduate",
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20,),
                Text(" Yana kadırarak menünüz icin bir resim secin",textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Graduate", fontSize: 12),),
                SizedBox(height: 20,),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemCount: stickerList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context,index){
                      return Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                          color: index == selectedIndex ?
                          _containerForStickersActiveColor :
                          _containerForStickersInactiveColor,
                        ),
                        child:TextButton(
                          child: Image(
                            image: AssetImage("images/sticker$index.png"),
                          ),
                          onPressed: (){
                            setState(() {
                              selectedIndex = index;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                        );
                      }
                    ),
                  ),
                SizedBox(height: 20,),
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(style: BorderStyle.solid),
                    color: kColorTheme7,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(90),
                  ),
                  child: TextButton(
                    onPressed: (){
                      if(widget.route=="homeScreen"){
                        Navigator.pop(context, ModalRoute.withName(HomeScreen.id));
                        Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>HomeScreen(newCategoryName: newCategoryName,
                            newCategoryImagePath: "images/sticker$selectedIndex.png")));
                      }
                      else if(widget.route=="subCategoryScreen"){
                        Navigator.pop(context, ModalRoute.withName(SubCategoriesScreen.id));
                        Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>SubCategoriesScreen(categoryId: widget.categoryId,subCategoryName: newCategoryName,
                          subCategoryImagePath:"images/sticker$selectedIndex.png" )));
                      }
                    },
                    child: Text(widget.buttonText, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color:  Colors.white,
                        fontFamily: "Graduate", fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class _SubCategoriesScreenState extends State<SubCategoriesScreen> {

  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    if(widget.categoryId!=null && widget.subCategoryImagePath!=null && widget.subCategoryName!=null){
      addSubCategory();
      }
    }

    void addSubCategory(){
      SubCategoryModel subCategoryModel=SubCategoryModel(
          subCategoryId:widget.categoryId,
          subCategoryImagePath: widget.subCategoryImagePath,
          subCategoryName: widget.subCategoryName,
          categoryColor: Color((Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt()).withOpacity(0.5));
      if(categoryModels!=null){
        for (var categoryModel in categoryModels){
          if (categoryModel.categoryId == subCategoryModel.subCategoryId){
            categoryModel.subCategoryModels.insert(categoryModel.subCategoryModels.length-1,subCategoryModel);
          }
        }
      }
    }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          centerTitle: true,
          title: BorderedText(
            child:Text(
              categoryModels[widget.categoryId].categoryName,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0XFFFFFB00),
                  fontSize: 30,
                  fontFamily: "Graduate"
              ),
            ),
            strokeWidth: 5,
            strokeColor: Colors.black,
          ),
          elevation: 5,
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF2C3D4).withOpacity(1),
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            onPressed: (){
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            iconSize: 40,
            color: Color(0xFFA2000B),
          ),
          actions: [
            CircleAvatar(
              radius: 27,
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              backgroundImage: AssetImage("images/cuttedlogo.PNG"),
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("images/logoBGopacity.png"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: GridView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
                    itemCount:categoryModels[widget.categoryId].subCategoryModels.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context,index){
                      if(categoryModels[widget.categoryId].subCategoryModels[index].subCategoryId==-1){
                        return EmptyCard(where: "subCategoryScreen");
                      }
                      return SubCategoryCard(subCategoryId:widget.categoryId,subcategoryName: categoryModels[widget.categoryId].subCategoryModels[index].subCategoryName,
                        subCategoryImagePath: categoryModels[widget.categoryId].subCategoryModels[index].subCategoryImagePath,
                        subCategoryColor: categoryModels[widget.categoryId].subCategoryModels[index].categoryColor,);
                    }
                ),
              ),
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(style: BorderStyle.solid),
                        color: kColorTheme7,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                      ),
                      child: TextButton(
                        onPressed: (){
                          showModalBottomSheet(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (BuildContext context)=> AddMenuScreen(categoryId:widget.categoryId,buttonText: "Tarif Ekle", route:"subCategoryScreen"),
                          );
                        },
                        child: BorderedText(
                          strokeWidth: 5,
                          strokeColor: Colors.black,
                          child:Text("Tarif Ekle",style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontFamily:'Graduate',
                            fontSize:30,
                          ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Error:

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following ArgumentError was thrown building SubCategoriesScreen(dirty, state: _SubCategoriesScreenState#72f75):
Invalid argument(s)

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  SubCategoriesScreen file:///C:/Users/yagiz/AndroidStudioProjects/lezzet_kitabi/lib/screens/add_menu_screen.dart:121:98
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:254:60)
#1      _SubCategoriesScreenState.build (package:lezzet_kitabi/screens/subCategoriesScreen.dart:61:29)
#2      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4742:27)
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4625:15)
#4      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4797:11)
```

Comment: Can you add an error to the question?

Comment: I added, thnx..